# Block event change if click inside or outside the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some problem how to block event change if click inside or outside the input.

```
<input type="number" id="tenure-long" value="2" min="1" max="10" />

$( document ).on( 'keyup change', '#tenure-long', function( e ) {
    // fire function
});

// try block with this, but not working
$( document ).on( 'click', 'body', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I want, if user after change input value and click on other element of page don't fire change event again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'body', function(event){
  if (event.target.id !== 'ternure-log') {
    $('#tenure-long').attr('disabled','disabled')
  }
});
```

If you click somewhere else you can disable your input in this way won't be possible change it's value again.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/xuputubopo/edit?html,js,console,output) you have a live demo.

Comment: Thanks for answer, if the value after change manualy and click another element keep fire change :(

Comment: Did you see the demo? it's working in the way you want right? or maybe I'm missing something?